# Unable to login with users in Active Directory in wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've configured the `wso2 api manager` with external LDAP i.e. `Microsoft Active Directory.` Connectivity is set up and I'm able to see all the users in WSO2 apim user store which are present in AD. I have `4` following users in AD

```
Users : WSo2 Admin, WSO2 User1, WSO2 User2
```

But I'm able to login with just one user which I'm assigning the `admin` role in configuration file like below snippet.

`<AdminUser>
  <UserName>Wso2 Admin</UserName>
  <Password>abcdef@01</Password>
</AdminUser>`

Now I'll be only able to login with `WSo2 Admin` only, same happens for other users if I assign admin role in config file I'll be able to login.

But i want to login with every user which are present in AD i.e. `WSo2 Admin, WSO2 User1, WSO2 User2`

Here is my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
            <AddAdmin>false</AddAdmin>
            <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
                <UserName>Wso2 Admin</UserName>
                <Password>abcdef@01</Password>
            </AdminUser>
            <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName>
            <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
            <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="initializeNewClaimManager">true</Property>
            <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://test.xxxx.com:389</Property> 
            <Property name="ConnectionName">CN=Wso2 Admin,OU=wso2test,DC=test,DC=xxxx,DC=com</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">abcdef@01</Property>
            <Property name="AnonymousBind">false</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">OU=wso2test,DC=test,DC=xxxx,DC=com</Property>
            <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">user</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=user)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=user)</Property>
            <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute"/>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">OU=wso2test,DC=test,DC=xxxx,DC=com</Property>
            <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">group</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=group)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectcategory=group)</Property>
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
            <Property name="MemberOfAttribute">memberOf</Property>
            <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="Referral">follow</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._\-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password length should be within 5 to 30 characters</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._\-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="IsBulkImportSupported">true</Property>
            <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
            <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
            <Property name="isADLDSRole">false</Property>
            <Property name="userAccountControl">512</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>     
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>                     
            <Property name="MembershipAttributeRange">1500</Property>
            <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="defaultRealmName">WSO2.ORG</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
            <Property name="ReadTimeout"/>
            <Property name="RetryAttempts"/>
        </UserStoreManager>

        <AuthorizationManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
            <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
            <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">true</Property>
        </AuthorizationManager>
    </Realm>
</UserManager>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the administrative console only admins (members of the admin group) are allowed to log in.

If you want any user to log in, you may try to find role `Internal/everyone` and add a permission `Login` to the role.

However the users by default will be able only to change their password (even that's not true until you use ldaps connection instead of ldap)

Comment: I created a new role, gave it login permission from the tree and assigned the required users to that role. I'm able to login with all the users!